# Using CHttpFile with HTTPS sites

Tags: https, mfc

I have this code that I use to read a data file from my website:

```
CInternetSession    iSession;
CHttpFile           *pWebFile = nullptr;
DWORD               dwStatusCode;
CString             strError, strTargetZIP, strDownloadURL;

strTargetZIP = theApp.GetWorkingPath() + _T("AutoUpdate\\MWBDataUpdate.zip");
strDownloadURL = _T("http://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/mwbdata/MWBDataUpdate.zip");

// ask user to go online
if (InternetGoOnline((LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)strDownloadURL, hWnd, 0))
{
    TRY
    {
        // our session should already be open
        // try to open up internet session to my URL
        // Use flag INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD
        pWebFile = (CHttpFile*)iSession.OpenURL(strDownloadURL, 1,
        INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_BINARY | INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD);

        if (pWebFile != nullptr)
        {
            if (pWebFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwStatusCode))
            {
                // 20x codes mean success
                if ((dwStatusCode / 100) == 2)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    // There was a problem!
                    strError.Format(IDS_TPL_INVALID_URL, dwStatusCode);
                    AfxMessageBox(strError, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Note, there is no error log.  Use new error message?
            AfxMessageBox(IDS_STR_UPDATE_CHECK_ERR, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }
    }
    CATCH(CException, e)
    {
        e->GetErrorMessage(szError, _MAX_PATH);
        AfxMessageBox(szError, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    END_CATCH

    // Tidy up
    if (pWebFile != nullptr)
    {
        pWebFile->Close();
        delete pWebFile;
    }
    iSession.Close();
}
```

I have recently changed my site to use `HTTPS` and I am trying to find if all I need to do is just change the `URL` here in my code. I have looked up the latest documentation for [`CHttpFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/chttpfile-class) and it only mentions `HTTP`.

Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CInternetSession::OpenURL` calls [`InternetOpenUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098(v=vs.85).aspx) API. `InternetOpenUrl` needs `INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` for secure websites.

Change the url from `http://` to `https://`

Add `INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` to `OpenURL`'s option.

Example:

```
CInternetSession isession;
CString url = _T("https://www.google.com");
CString filename = _T("c:\\test\\test.html");
CHttpFile *httpfile = (CHttpFile*)isession.OpenURL(url, 1, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE |
    INTERNET_FLAG_TRANSFER_BINARY | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD);
if (httpfile)
{
    DWORD dwStatusCode;
    httpfile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwStatusCode);
    if(dwStatusCode == 200)
    {
        char buf[0x1000] = { 0 };
        DWORD read = 0;
        CFile file;
        if (file.Open(filename, CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite))
            while(InternetReadFile(*httpfile, buf, sizeof(buf), &read) && read)
                file.Write(buf, read);
    }

    httpfile->Close();
    delete httpfile;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I clarify? Here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383661(v=vs.85).aspx I see: “This flag is used by HttpOpenRequest and InternetOpenUrl, but this is redundant if https:// appears in the URL.”. So am I right in saying I either leave the URL as it is and use this flag, or leave flags alone and use HTTPS prefix?

Comment: Yes, apparently `INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` is optional if url starts with `"https://"`. I didn't notice that before.